# How to prevent colors from blending?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Consider the following example:

```xml
<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Line Stroke="Red" X1="0" X2="100" Y1="50" Y2="50"/>
    <Line Stroke="Red" X1="50" X2="50" Y1="0" Y2="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Despite the fact that both lines have SolidColorBrush and both have opacity=1, a color blending still occurs: The pixel at the point of intersection is of darker red color.

Why does it happen and how can I prevent it?

Thanks!

P.S Here is another example of the same code with the brushes explicitly defined:

```xml
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Line}">
            <Setter Property="Stroke">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="1" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Line X1="0" X2="100" Y1="50" Y2="50" />
    <Line X1="50" X2="50" Y1="0" Y2="100" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to look into *[snapping to pixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx)*. This is a feature of WPF that allows for some extra granularity in rendering. Say if we take a `Line` and apply this:

```
<Line X1="0" X2="100" Y1="50" Y2="50" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
```

As an example of what this serves to do, here's an image from the linked article:

[image]

Comment: Oh man, it is the second time the answer to my question is SnapsToDevicePixels. I should really start paying more attention to that property. Thanks!!